# FireFox and Chrome display different html page

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm a newbie and I have tried hard to get out a page.

After many trail and error this page finally looks "ok" though some of the part I don't know how I get it "right"

But when my page is opened in Firefox its bloody twisted! the table jumped out of boundary.

here is the format in chrome and IE(which is right)
[image]

and this is the format in firefox

[image]

the table shift out of the container and shift up.

I've search about use css reset but I dun't know how to do it,(what should I add to where)
or I should edit my html or css?which part of css I need to edit?

thanks in advance！

Comment: Wow! Magic! P.S. Add some code or it will still be a magic.

Comment: Can u please show your code?

Comment: You can also share the site URL.

Comment: @inaamhusain the code of html or css? I didn't post cause they are really a mess,I'll add some html part first

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya sorry but this site require login for internal use.so I'll provide some html code

Comment: @Orz and what css u have used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by put all shifted table into a container to fix them.
and it works! thanks guys for helping me.